# Microsoft Online CRM 2011, is it possible to connect without using the SDK

Tags: web-services, sdk, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have started experimenting with Microsoft CRM 2011 online, i followed the instructions and installed the sdk. And everything is working. My problem is that i do not understand why i have to use a SDK when im accessing a webservice.

Is there any way of connecting to the webwervice (IOrganizationService) and get both metadata and data? That is - so i dont have to distribute the SDK with my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like its a half solution they made with this one. You need the SDK for some datatypes, and some datatypes is coming from the proxy generated from the wsdl. it does not seem to be a "proper" webservice hosting all datatypes. Well, they have the datatypes, but only for transport, the real implementation is in another partial class in the SDK.